# Help with Proof in Multivariable Calc Class

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

**My assignment is to prove the following:**

A scalar-valued function f : S → R defined on a nonempty set S ⊆ R
d is said to be continuous at the point p ∈ S if each ε > 0 determines a corresponding δ > 0 such that all

x ∈ S ∩ Bδ(p) satisfy f(x) ∈ Bε(f(p)) = (f(p) − ε, f(p) + ε). We say that f is continuous on S if f is continuous at each point p ∈ S.

Let f : S → R be a continuous function whose domain S happens to be open. Given some

number a ∈ R, the strict a-sublevel set
[[f < a]] := {x ∈ S | f(x) < a}

and strict a-superlevel set

[[f > a]] := {x ∈ S | f(x) > a},

as well as the a-nonlevel set

[[f 6= a]] := [[f < a]] ∪ [[f > a]],

are all open.

**This is what I have so far for my proof, but I cannot seem to figure out where to go from here:**
Let Q ⊆ [f < a] s.t. Q ∈ S and f(s)<a. Then, ε := a-ε(Q)>0. The ε corresponds to some δ > 0 s.t. and x ⊆ s with dist (x, Q)< δ satisfies |f(x)-f(Q))| < ε because f is a continuous function.

Comment: Hi Joshua. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: I can't understand your question. What are you trying to prove?

Comment: I have edited the assignment wording to better explain what is required of me